# Cannot install xdebug with WAMP SERVER 2.1

Tags: wamp, xdebug, php

I use WAMP SERVER 2.1 and select PHP 5.3.3 for my system, so I select xDebug with php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll and changed name becoming php_xdebug.dll for easy way to use.

Following the instructions: php.ini (in Apache folder)

```
extension=php_xdebug.dll
...
zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

However, nothing happens, there are no information related to xdebug from phpinfo. Also xdebug announce that xdebug have not installed yet (http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php).

I am so worried causing too much time for configuration. I got crazy and totally **gave up**.
Anyone have ideas to solve it, I am so appreciated what you help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your Apache server? I believe that in WAMP's menu, there should be an option to restart the server.

Comment: yes, every time I modified anything then I also restart WAMP. As I said,no thing happens

Answer (score 0):

I think for XDebug to load properly, it needs one of the following lines of code. Anytime I used the setup from [this site](http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug), XDebug did not load. The following snippet of php.ini is the configuration on all my development systems.

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
; Modify the filename below to reflect the .dll version of your xdebug
zend_extension="C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.6\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost  ; if debugging on remote server,
                          ; put client IP here
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\wamp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\wamp\tmp"
```

Also check [this website](http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php) to make sure you have the proper XDebug dll. I once had a problem of using a vc9 dll on a vc6 system.